# ASPxGridView , LinqServerModeDataSourceForGrid, How to sort on grid? How to sort columns in devexpress dynamically grid?

Tags: c#, sorting, devexpress, aspxgridview, gridview-sorting

How to sort on grid?
How to sort columns in devexpress dynamically  grid?

AutoGenerateColumns="true", runat="server"

dx:LinqServerModeDataSource

I am creating the columns dynamically but sorting on my grid is not working.

I tried many ways, my grids are working but I can't sort on any of the columns.

I am pulling data from database through another project and making databind for ID="ASPxGridViewData". grid and structure are working but sorting is not working, what is the missing way?

[devexpress grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZDwg.jpg)

aspx code;

```
 <div id="divDisplayFeatures" class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;display:none">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <dx:ASPxWebDocumentViewer ID="ASPxWebDocumentViewerForReport" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Visible="false"
            ClientSideEvents-DocumentReady="function(s,e){ $('.dxrd-image-parameters').hide(); if($('#HiddenFieldPrintStatus').val() == 1) { s.Print(); }}">
        </dx:ASPxWebDocumentViewer>
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridViewData" runat="server"
            ClientIDMode="Static"
            AutoGenerateColumns="true"
            Styles-Header-BackColor="#ff7f00"
            Styles-Header-Font-Bold="true"
            Styles-Header-Font-Size="Small"
            Styles-PagerBottomPanel-BackColor="#ff7f00"
            Width="100%"
            Visible="false"
            AllowSorting="true"
            Settings-AutoFilterCondition="Contains"
            Settings-HorizontalScrollBarMode="Visible"
            Settings-ShowFilterRow="true"
            DataSourceID="LinqServerModeDataSourceForGrid"
            OnDataBound="ASPxGridViewData_DataBound"
            Styles-Header-Wrap="True">
            <Columns ></Columns>
            <SettingsPager PageSizeItemSettings-Items="5,10,25,50,100,200,500" PageSizeItemSettings-Visible="true"></SettingsPager>
        </dx:ASPxGridView>

        <dx:LinqServerModeDataSource ID="LinqServerModeDataSourceForGrid" runat="server" DefaultSorting="Id desc" 
            OnSelecting="LinqServerModeDataSourceForGrid_Selecting"></dx:LinqServerModeDataSource>
```

c# code;

```
protected string GetGridFilterString(DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView grid)
    {
        var parse = DevExpress.Data.Filtering.CriteriaOperator.Parse(
                    grid.FilterExpression, 0);

        var gridFilter =
            DevExpress.Data.Filtering.CriteriaToWhereClauseHelper.GetDataSetWhere(
                parse);

        return gridFilter;
    }
    protected void DisplayReportView(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            panelButtons.Visible = true;
            GenerateReportView(ReportGenerateType.Gridview);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ActivityLogManager.WriteLog(SmartFrame.Products.Enum.ProcessType.GenerateWebReport, ex.Message, SmartFrame.Products.Enum.ProcessStatus.FAILED);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    protected void GenerateReportView(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            GenerateReportView(ReportGenerateType.Report);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ActivityLogManager.WriteLog(SmartFrame.Products.Enum.ProcessType.GenerateWebReport, ex.Message, SmartFrame.Products.Enum.ProcessStatus.FAILED);
            throw ex;
        }
    }



private void GenerateReportView(ReportGenerateType ReportGenerateType)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PageData.ReportCode))
            {
                #region Set Report Parameters
                var currentSystemUser = HttpContext.Current.Session["currentSystemUser"] as SmartFrame.SmartBase.NoSQL.Collections.SystemUser;
                var selectedFacility = HttpContext.Current.Session["selectedFacility"] as SmartFrame.SmartBase.NoSQL.Collections.Facility;
                var reportParameters = new SmartFrame.Report.Client.ReportContainer();
                var myStations = new List<Station>();

                if (SmartFrame.SmartBase.NoSQL.DataProvider.allStations.Where(x => x.FacilityID == selectedFacility.Id && currentSystemUser.Stations.Contains(x.Id)).ToList() != null)
                    myStations = SmartFrame.SmartBase.NoSQL.DataProvider.allStations.Where(x => x.FacilityID == selectedFacility.Id && currentSystemUser.Stations.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();

                reportParameters.ReportSource = SmartFrame.Products.Enum.RequestSource.Web;
                reportParameters.ReportCreatorUser = currentSystemUser.UserName;
                reportParameters.ReportType = PageData.ReportCode;
                reportParameters.ReportHeaderLogoPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Resources\StockArtLogo_Black.png";
                reportParameters.ReportHeaderTitle = LanguageProvider.GetLanguageText(HttpContext.Current.Session["currentLanguage"] as String, "ReportType" + PageData.ReportCode);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DatetimeStartDateTime.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(DatetimeEndDateTime.Text))
                {
                    DateTime enteredDateStartDate = DateTime.Parse(DatetimeStartDateTime.Text);
                    DateTime enteredDateEndDate = DateTime.Parse(DatetimeEndDateTime.Text);
                    reportParameters.StartTime = enteredDateStartDate;
                    reportParameters.EndTime = enteredDateEndDate;
                }

                HiddenFieldPrintStatus.Value = "0";
                var selectedTemplate = new SmartFrame.SmartBase.NoSQL.Collections.UserReportTemplateSetting();
                PageData.ReportFieldSettings = new List<SmartFrame.SmartBase.NoSQL.RelatedClasses.ReportFieldSettings>();
                var reportFilterSettings = new List<SmartFrame.SmartBase.NoSQL.RelatedClasses.ReportFilterSetting>();


                var selectedTemplateId = Request["ctl00$MainContent$SelectForReportTemplates"];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedTemplateId))
                {
                    selectedTemplateId = Request["ctl00$MainContent$HiddenFieldSelectedTemplateId"];
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedTemplateId))
                {
                    selectedTemplate = genericController.GetOne<UserReportTemplateSetting>(x => x.Id == selectedTemplateId);
                    PageData.ReportFieldSettings = selectedTemplate.FieldSettingsList;
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    selectedTemplate = null;
                    PageData.ReportFieldSettings = null;
                }

                #endregion
                switch (PageData.ReportCode)
                {
                    case "A01":



                        if (ReportGenerateType == ReportGenerateType.Gridview)
                        {
                            var reportInstance = new SmartFrame.Report.Client.TwentyLeastUsedItemsReport(reportParameters);

                            if (PageData.ReportFieldSettings == null)
                                PageData.ReportFieldSettings = reportInstance.GenerateDefaultFieldSettings(new List<SmartFrame.SmartBase.NoSQL.RelatedClasses.ReportFieldSettings>());

                            reportInstance.InitializeReportData(reportInstance.FilterParameterDataList);

                            genericController.InitializeQueryableSession<SmartFrame.Report.DataSource.TwentyLeastUsedItemsData>("ExternalDataSource" + PageData.DynamicPageId);
                            Session["ExternalDataSource" + PageData.DynamicPageId] = reportInstance.GetReportDataQueryable().OrderBy(x => x.ItemName).OrderBy(x => x.Station);
                            ASPxGridViewData.DataBind();
                        }.............................
```

.....................................................
............................................
...........................................................
............................................................
...............................................

```
protected void LinqServerModeDataSourceForGrid_Selecting(object sender, DevExpress.Data.Linq.LinqServerModeDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        ASPxGridViewData.Columns.Clear();
        ASPxGridViewData.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

        e.KeyExpression = "Id";
        e.QueryableSource = (IsCallback || IsPostBack) ?
                Session["ExternalDataSource" + PageData.DynamicPageId] as IQueryable<object> :
                new List<object>().AsQueryable();
    }
```

how to sort on grid?

Comment: Hi, please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body. Goodluck 

Comment: Thanks, I've updated it, do you think it's clear enough?

Comment: yes, it's better now.